# Cannot import name 'tf2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a `v.environment` where I have Python version 3.6.5 and there I installed `tensorflow-gpu`.
The version of TensorFlow is 1.4.0 and of Keras is 2.6.0.
When I write on the script `import keras` it appears the following Error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'tf2'

Have you any idea?

Comment: I think the problems caused by the TF is too old, and the keras is too new. Your choice is to downgrade keras to something below 2.3.0, or use newer version of tf

Comment: Thanks, this solved a problem. I choose keras==2.2.1 because with 2.3.0 I had another error.

Answer (score 2):

From comments

> Here the problem caused by the `TF` is too old, and the `keras` is
> too new. Your choice is to downgrade `keras` to `2.2.1`, or use newer
> version of `tf` (paraphrased by Vinson Ciawandy & homomathematicus)